# PHP Function not returning variable correctly

Tags: php, function, variables, curl

I am having difficulty with this code:

```
function convert($file, $name){
    global $apiKey, $uploadDir, $fname, $lname, $fileNam, $wpdb, $ewd_feup_user_fields_table_name, $conn, $usrID;

    $endpoint = "https://api.zamzar.com/v1/jobs";
    $sourceFilePath = $file;
    $targetFormat = "html5";

    $sql = "SELECT Field_Value FROM $ewd_feup_user_fields_table_name WHERE Job_ID ='$jobId' AND User_ID = '$usrID' ";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    //CHECK TO SEE IF THEY HAVE ALREADY CONVERTED FILE
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        // echo "The file you want to convert Already Exists";
        return "not here";
    }
    //ELSE CONVERT AND WRITE JOB ID TO SERVER
    else{
        // Since PHP 5.5+ CURLFile is the preferred method for uploading files
        if(function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
          $sourceFile = curl_file_create($sourceFilePath);
        } else {
          $sourceFile = '@' . realpath($sourceFilePath);
        }

        $postData = array(
          "source_file" => $sourceFile,
          "target_format" => $targetFormat
        );

        //PULL FILE INFO AS ARRAY
        $ch = curl_init(); // Init curl
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint); // API endpoint
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false); // Enable the @ prefix for uploading files
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Return response as a string
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiKey . ":"); // Set the API key as the basic auth username
        $body = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $response = json_decode($body, true);

        //get ID from array
        $jobID = $response['id'];

        //update on server
        $sql = "UPDATE $ewd_feup_user_fields_table_name SET Field_Value='$jobID' WHERE User_ID='$usrID' AND Field_Name='Job ID' ";
        $conn->query($sql);

        //return
        return $jobID;      
    }   
}`
```

This code simply pulls an array from the source and retrieves the ID of the `job`. After retrieving it, I return it in `$jobID`.
The following code is supposed to use `$jobID` to gather another ID called `$fileID`:

```
function get_file_id($z){
    global $apiKey, $uploadDir, $fname, $lname, $fileNam, $wpdb, $ewd_feup_user_fields_table_name, $conn, $usrID;

    $endpoint = "https://api.zamzar.com/v1/jobs/$z";

    $ch = curl_init(); // Init curl
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint); // API endpoint
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Return response as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiKey . ":"); // Set the API key as the basic auth username
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $job = json_decode($body, true);

    $fileI = $job['target_files']['0']['id'];

    $sql = "UPDATE $ewd_feup_user_fields_table_name SET Field_Value='$fileI' WHERE User_ID='$usrID' AND Field_Name='File ID' ";
    $conn->query($sql);

    echo $fileI;
    //echo "Done.";
}
```

When I attempt to use the returned value from `convert();` the `get_file_id();` code does not return anything.

```
$conv = convert($uploadDir."Carlos Hernandez.docx", "Carlos Hernandez.docx");
get_file_id($conv);
```

Comment: Use `var_dump()` to check the status of `$conv` and `$fileI`. Do `var_dump($conv);` and `var_dump($fileI);` and see what you're getting.

Comment: var_dump($conv); Returns => int(595404) and var_dump($fileI); Returns => NULL @RajdeepPaul

Comment: Now check the status of decoded json string, do `var_dump($job);`.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I see where you are going. It returns: ` int(595436)
array(10) {
  ["source_file"]=&gt;
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=&gt;
    int(16402805)
    ["name"]=&gt;
    string(21) "Carlos Hernandez.docx"
    ["size"]=&gt;
    int(91381)
  }
  ["target_files"]=&gt;
  array(0) {
  } ` I shortened it so its easier for you to see. The array i am pulling from is NULL. I understood that from the beginning. The issue is that when I run the code (after about 10 secs) using the same ID -> it works.

Comment: There you go, `["target_files"] => array(0) { }` (empty array), that's why you're not getting any file id.

Comment: Yes! But when I run my get_file_id() after it fails. It succeeds in pulling the File ID. @RajdeepPaul Could it be that the file takes time to convert with the client API?

Comment: I believe it's a timeout issue. Add this two lines `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);` after `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiKey . ":");`

Comment: Should i make the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT longer? Say 800? @RajdeepPaul

Comment: You could, but I don't think it will make any difference if `400` didn't work.

Comment: It worked!! Thank you. @RajdeepPaul